# How to create an existing Git repository

Tags: windows, git, github, github-for-windows

I've got a repository. When downloading this repo, instead of cloning it, it seems that I accidentally simply downloaded the source instead. Now I've come to commit my changes and noticed that the folder I'm working in is, in fact, not a repository at all but just some random folder.

I've found various ways of initializing a *new* repo from existing contents. But how can I initialize an *existing* repo from my existing contents? I added the remote repo as a remote in the GitHub for Windows client, but it doesn't seem to have had the desired effect.

Just to be clear, the intended outcome is as if I had cloned it properly in the first place- history, diffs of the changes I've made from the latest in the repo, the works.

I've tried some solutions involving git clone, like "Clone into a new folder and then just copy and paste the .git folder". However, this seems to have the effect that Git thinks that I deleted and re-added every line of every file in the repository instead of the changes I really made.

Comment: Instead of copying over the .git folder, why not copy over the contents of the repository that you had originally "cloned" then modified to the properly cloned repository?  My gut feeling is that Git would be able to identify the deltas that you had introduced (provided that it was properly set to deal with CRLF endings per file).

Comment: You would be correct- Git correctly found the deltas when I copied the changes into the repo instead of the repo into the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what we talked about in the comments, you should copy over the actual data to the properly cloned repository as opposed to the `.git` folder.  This way, Git has a chance to pick up the changes without introducing any aberrant or unusual state issues.